# How to do sub plot using sas

Tags: sas

I want to make a simple time series line plot without highlighting any dots on the line. I can plot var1 and var2 using the following code.

```
   title "Title";
   proc gplot data=test;

      plot var1 *var2 /overlay grid  hminor=0 ;
   run;
   quit;
```

However I want to add another variable into the plot. I tried the following code. Because the scale of `var1` and `var3` are quite large, so var3 are not properly scaled in the graph. Can anyone teach me how to use different scale for var1 and var3 please.

```
   title "Title";
   proc gplot data=Test;

      plot var1 *var2   Var3*var2 /overlay grid  hminor=0 ;
   run;
   quit;
```

Additionally, may I ask whether sas can do subplot as matlab please. Essentially, I got one big graph with two separate sub-graph. If possible, please teach me how to achieve this. I tried vpercent = 50, but it seems there are something wrong in my code.

```
   proc gplot data=Test  vpercent=50;

      plot VAR1 *VAR2   VAR3*VAR2 /overlay grid  hminor=0 ;

   run;
   quit;
```

With Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understand what you mean, if you have access to SGPLOT you can specify that X3 should be on a different axis. Here's an example with the SASHELP.STOCKS data which plots the open price on one Y axis and then the trade volume on the second Y axis.

```
proc sgplot data=sashelp.stocks;
where stock='IBM';
series x=date y=open;
series x=date y=volume/y2axis;
run;quit;
```

Comment: Thanks it works.  May I ask if SAS can produce a graph with two sub-graph. Instead of plotting two variable on the same graph, I want to put one plot on top, and the other plot on the bottom.

Comment: You'll need to post an example, but you could look into either SGSCATTER or SGPANEL.

Comment: Thanks! what I want to achieve is shown in  `Plots Produced with VPERCENT=50`  section     http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/68381/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0jbod8p3l9txtn1gkuq2jvpj9nr.htm    I try to implement this in the last part of my code but it does not work. Can you have a look and see how to change my code and achieve this please

Answer (score 1):

Here is some SAS code that builds on Reeza's excellent example and suggestion to use SGPANEL.  See the PANELBY statement and the options used there.

```
*** SUBSET DATA AND SORT ***;
proc sort data=sashelp.stocks  out=ibm;
    where stock='IBM';
    by date;
run;

*** TRANSPOSE DATA FROM "SHORT-AND-WIDE" TO "LONG-AND-THIN" ***;
proc transpose data=ibm  out=ibm_t;
    by date;
    var open volume;
run;


proc sgpanel data=ibm_t;

    *** ROW LATTICE OPTION STACKS PLOTS ***;
    *** UNISCALE OPTION LETS EACH PANEL HAVE IT'S OWN SCALE ***;
    *** NOVARNAME SUPPRESSES LABEL FOR THE Y-AXIS ON THE RIGHT SIDE ***;
    panelby _name_ / layout=rowlattice uniscale=column novarname;

    series x=date y=col1;

    *** SUPPRESS LABEL FOR THE Y-AXIS ON THE LEFT SIDE ***;
    rowaxis display=(nolabel);
run;
```